# "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" With python2 metaclass converted to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, metaclass

I'm converting some code from python2 to python3 and I'm hitting an error with a metaclass.

This is the working python2 code (simplified):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# test2.py

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict):
        new_class = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict)
        return new_class

class Root(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        super(Root, self).__init__()

class Sub(Root):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(value=value)

    def __new__(cls, value=None):
        super(Sub, cls).__new__(cls, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = Sub(1)
```

And here's the converted python3 code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# test3.py

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict):
        new_class = type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, clsdict)
        return new_class

class Root(object, metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        super(Root, self).__init__()

class Sub(Root):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(Sub, self).__init__(value=value)

    def __new__(cls, value=None):
        super(Sub, cls).__new__(cls, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = Sub(1)
```

If I run `python2 test2.py`, it runs. If I do `python3 test3.py`, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    sub = Sub(1)
  File "test.py", line 18, in __new__
    super(Sub, cls).__new__(cls, value)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

This isn't a duplicate of the linked question because in that one the asker wasn't invoking a simple class correctly. In this one I have code which worked in python 2 and doesn't work with 2to3 run on it

Comment: You would have seen a warning about this in Python 2, except that DeprecationWarnings are suppressed by default. [Here's the long-ass comment about why `object.__init__` and `object.__new__` handle extra arguments in the weird way they do.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l2817)

Comment: Also, the metaclass has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance: why is `Root` still inheriting from `object`?

Comment: @Pynchia no reason other than the fact that it hasn't been changed yet. AFAIK it doesn't change behavior vs not declaring a parent in python 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: object() takes no parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078742/typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters)

Comment: Side-question: Why is `__new__` only being overridden for `Sub`, not `Root`? Usually, `__init__` is for mutable types, `__new__` for immutable, and it's nonsensical to make an immutable subclass of a mutable class (since the superclass would remain mutable); often, people just use `__init__` for everything on the "we're all adults here" principle. Also, as written, `__new__` for `Sub` is wrong since it doesn't return the newly created object even if it did manage to create it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm updating some legacy code. I suspect this is one of the cases of "old code" they didn't want to break in python 2

Comment: @Daenyth: That still wouldn't make sense; support for `__init__` is common to all versions of Python; even if you wanted to keep support for inheriting from old-style classes, you could just use `__init__` exclusively. Beyond that, using `super` means you're implicitly relying on new-style classes anyway; it doesn't work with old-style classes.

Comment: I didn't write it, so I don't know the motivation behind doing it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [described in depth by a comment in the Python 2 source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l2817) (as linked by user2357112 in a comment), Python considers it an error if you pass arguments to either `object.__new__` or `object.__init__` when both `__init__` and `__new__` have been overridden. If you override just one of those functions, the other one will ignore excess arguments, but if you override them both you're supposed to make sure you only pass on arguments that are appropriate.

In this case, your `Root` class overrides `__init__` but not `__new__`, so the extra argument that gets passed to the inherited `object.__new__`  when you create an instance are ignored.

However, in `Sub`, you're overriding both functions, and `Sub.__new__` passes the parameter `value` on to `object.__new__` in its `super` call. This is where you get an exception.

It's technically an error in Python 2 as well as Python 3, but the Python developers decided that raising an exception in that situation would cause too much old code to break, so Python 2 only issues a warning (which is suppressed by default). Python 3 breaks backwards compatibility in several other ways, so breaking old code for this issue as well is not as big a deal.

Anyway, the proper way to fix your code is either to add a `__new__` method to `Root` that accepts and suppresses the `value` argument (e.g. it doesn't pass it on to `object.__new__`), or to change `Sub` so that it doesn't pass the value to its parent at all (e.g. it just calls `super(Sub, cls).__new__(cls)`). You might want to think a bit about whether you actually need both `__new__` and `__init__` methods in `Sub`, since most classes only need to override one of them.