# Classes in Python - TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Tags: python, class, object, python-3.4

I'm new to python, and I'm having a problem getting this little bit of code to work. I keep running into this same issue. When I run this I get the error message:

```
TypeError: object() takes no parameters.
```

I've included the error message in full below.

Here's my code:

```
class Bird:
    _type = ""

    def bird(self, type):
        self._type = type

    def display(self):
        print(self._type)


class Species:
    _bird = None
    _type = ""

    def set_bird(self, bird):
        self._bird = bird

    def display(self):
        print(self._type)
        self._bird.display(self)


class Cardinal(Species):
    def cardinal(self):
        self._type = "Cardinal"


def main():
    species = Cardinal()
    species.set_bird(Bird("Red"))
    species.display()


main()
```

[image: error message]

Comment: You are getting confused about how to declare a constructor. In python you use `__init__` not the name of the class. Even if iy was that way why would a class `Bird` have a constructor `bird`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078742/typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are doing:

```
species.set_bird(Bird("Red"))
```

While creating the object of `Bird`, you are passing argument `"Red"`. But there is no `__init__()` function in `Bird` class to accept this argument. Your `Bird` class should be like:

```
class Bird:
    # _type = ""   <--- Not needed
    #                   Probably you miss understood it with the
    #                   part needed in `__init__()`

    def __init__(self, type):
        self._type = type

    def bird(self, type):
        self._type = type

    def display(self):
        print(self._type)
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed that problem. But now I'm getting a new error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MNK/Documents/hack.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/MNK/Documents/hack.py", line 32, in main
    species.display()
  File "/Users/MNK/Documents/hack.py", line 21, in display
    self._bird.display(self)

TypeError: display() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Please create a separate question for that. Also note, Python is note that Python is not Java. You do not need setter and getter functions here

Comment: @Matthew: Regarding you new error, replace `self._bird.display(self) ` with `self._bird.display() `

Answer (score 1):

You do not have `__init__()` function inside your `Bird` class, so you can not write:

```
Bird("Red")
```

If you want to pass an argument like that, you need to do:

```
class Bird:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    # The rest of your code here
```

Below, you can see the result:

```
>>> class Bird:
...     def __init__(self, color):
...         self.color = color
...
>>>
>>>
>>> b = Bird('Red')
>>> b.color
'Red'
```